# sqlachemy created mysql table, but I modified table now says 'unknown column url'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I added a url column in my table, and now sqlalchemy is saying 'unknown column url'.

Why isn't it updating the table?

There must be a setting when I create the session?

I am doing:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

Is there something I am missing?

I want it to update any table that doesn't have a property that I added to my Table structure in my python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure SQLAlchemy supports schema migration that well (atleast the last time I touched it, it wasn't there).

A couple of options.

1. Don't manually specify your tables. Use the `autoload` feature to have SQLAlchemy automatically read out the columns from your database. This will require tests to make sure that it works but you get the idea in generally. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
2. Try [SQLAlchemy migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/).
3. Manually update the table after you change the model specification.

Answer (score 1):

In cases when you just add new columns, you can safely use `metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` to update your schema from your class definitions.

However this will NOT modify existing columns or remove columns from DB schema if you remove them in SQLA definition.